# Building with one job inside MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

ALL,

What option should I set in my project in order for it to be build with 1 job?

The solution I currently have contains couple of DLLs and executable and I'm using MSVC 2017 Free Edition.

Right now when I click "Build Project" it starts building with multiple jobs. But because not all dependancies are satisfied - the build fails on the first try.

I need to build it with 1 batch ob in order to fix linking dependencies and then go back to multiple builds.

TIA!!

Comment: If the projects are dependent on each other you need to set the References for the projects dependent on the others (and *likely* also set the"Link dependent project libraries" as well). That will ensure your independent libs build before your dependent libs/programs build, and the former are available to be consumed by the latter.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I agree. But I need I need to know which project depends on what in order to do so. Hence the question. Let the computer do the work for me - not the other way around. Because if I build with one batch job I will see exactly who fail and for what library and will be able to set dependencies properly.

Comment: Right now I can't do that as multiple projects are building at the same time and it is hard to identify the dependencies.

Comment: So you don't know which of *your* projects are dependent on *your* other projects? Pardon the bluntness, VS isn't going to figure it out for you. You have to guide it. *You* are responsible for configuring your solution dependencies. Every multi-project build configuration system I've ever worked with, including basic `make`, has the same requirements. You are responsible for spelling out what is dependent on what. Once you've configured them a simple single-step "build solution" will what you want: one-click build. But you have to do your part *first*.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2022

Comment: @selbie, I know how to do that. I just need to know what to configure.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I should know this, should I? It's my project after all, right? And I did set some dependencies. But later I added another subproject and I guess didn't set its dependencies right. So what I'm looking for is something like `make -j1` instead of `make -j3` when building with gcc.

Comment: How many projects are we talking about here?  10's or 100's of projects in the same solution?

Comment: @selbie, 14 DLLs + executable.

Comment: This should be easy.  Just sketch out all the link time dependencies between binaries to build out a complete dependency tree. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @selbie, no. Is there a tool for that?

Comment: Do you understand linking, link-time dependencies, and how to look these up in each project's property page in Visual Studio?

Comment: @selbie, I understand linking and link-time dependencies, but I don't know how to look them up.